# Save Android ListView Header Footer ViewState

Tags: android, listview, footer, viewstate

I've added a header & footer to my listview both of which have edittext fields.  When I rotate the screen the edittext fields are cleared out - the state is not saved.  Is there a simple way to tell Android to save the state for header/footer rows?  Or do I have to manually save header/footer state myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find any way to automatically save the state.  I had to manually save the state by calling pageHeader.saveHierarchyState(bundle);